# Complex input/output in tensorflow/keras neural networks is possible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, complex-numbers

I've heard that is possible to feed a neural network built using tensorflow/keras with complex data and get a complex output specifying the "dtype" of each layer = tf.complex64 (or similar).

```py
X = K.Input(shape = (n_taps,1), dtype = tf.complex64)
fc1 = K.layers.LSTM(n_fc1,activation="tanh",dtype = tf.complex64)  (X)
```

The declaration of each single layer does not give errors but calling the second layer giving as argument the first layer (2nd line I mean) gives the following expected error:

> TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type complex64 of argument 'a'.

I did not understand if it's possible or not have this kind of network.
Has anyone more informations about this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's because `K.layers.LSTM` doesn't support `tf.complex64` types. You would need to implement the layer yourself. You should start by subclassing `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, of which you can find an example in the docs of [`tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer). The example is called the `SimpleDense` layer.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you know any layer already implemented that I can put in place of my LSTM layer that already support tf.complex64?

Comment: No not really. Let's try something else, why is your data complex? A complex number has a real and an imaginary part. So why not just represent your data as with `shape=(n_taps, 2)`? The `2` is for both the real and the imaginary part.

Comment: Yes I’ve already done in that way and it works. I was just trying to improve my results. Thank you a lot, now I ve clearer ideas.